# How to stop dropdown from opening on focus?

Tags: semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

Background: At time of writing, Fomantic-UI is the live-development fork of Semantic-UI which will one day be rolled into Semantic-UI and is for the mean time the de facto supported genus of Semantic-UI.

Issue: When the first focusable object on a page is a dropdown, then on page open the dropdown will open as if clicked.

Notes: I had this first happen in a modal situation and was confused by it, thinking it was an issue on the modal specifically, but I have since had the same thing on a plain page. I have used a modal case in the snippet below to illustrate because the SO snippet viewer does not trigger the behaviour you get on a plain page. Another user raised this as an issue on FUI's git and the support crew pointed out the answer which I am sharing here via this self-answered question.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({

  });

$('#b1').on('click', function(e) {

  $('#m1').modal('show')


})
```

```html
<link href="https://fomantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fomantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Click the 'show modal' button to open a modal. Note the language dropdown opens immediately.
  </p>

  <p>
    <button id='b1'>Show the modal</button>
  </p>

  <div id='m1' class="ui modal">
    <div class="header">Header</div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class='container'>

        <div class="ui floating dropdown labeled search icon button">
          <i class="world icon"></i>
          <span class="text">Select Language</span>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item">Arabic</div>
            <div class="item">Chinese</div>
            <div class="item">Danish</div>
            <div class="item">Dutch</div>
            <div class="item">English</div>
            <div class="item">French</div>
            <div class="item">German</div>
            <div class="item">Greek</div>
            <div class="item">Hungarian</div>
            <div class="item">Italian</div>
            <div class="item">Japanese</div>
            <div class="item">Korean</div>
            <div class="item">Lithuanian</div>
            <div class="item">Persian</div>
            <div class="item">Polish</div>
            <div class="item">Portuguese</div>
            <div class="item">Russian</div>
            <div class="item">Spanish</div>
            <div class="item">Swedish</div>
            <div class="item">Turkish</div>
            <div class="item">Vietnamese</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>
        Voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
        incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
        voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur</p>

    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui approve button">Approve</div>
      <div class="ui button">Neutral</div>
      <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a setting on the dropdown call.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
  showOnFocus: false
});
```

Pretty much does what it says on the tin - with showOnFocus set to True (the default setting) the dropdown will open when it gets focus. If the dropdown is the first focusable object on the page then it will therefore open immediately. To avoid this, actively set showOnFocus to False as in the snippet and the dropdown will keep its contents hidden until the user initiates the open process.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    showOnFocus: false
  });

$('#b1').on('click', function(e) {

  $('#m1').modal('show')


})
```

```html
<link href="https://fomantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fomantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Click the 'show modal' button to open a modal. Note the language dropdown opens immediately.
  </p>

  <p>
    <button id='b1'>Show the modal</button>
  </p>

  <div id='m1' class="ui modal">
    <div class="header">Header</div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class='container'>

        <div class="ui floating dropdown labeled search icon button">
          <i class="world icon"></i>
          <span class="text">Select Language</span>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item">Arabic</div>
            <div class="item">Chinese</div>
            <div class="item">Danish</div>
            <div class="item">Dutch</div>
            <div class="item">English</div>
            <div class="item">French</div>
            <div class="item">German</div>
            <div class="item">Greek</div>
            <div class="item">Hungarian</div>
            <div class="item">Italian</div>
            <div class="item">Japanese</div>
            <div class="item">Korean</div>
            <div class="item">Lithuanian</div>
            <div class="item">Persian</div>
            <div class="item">Polish</div>
            <div class="item">Portuguese</div>
            <div class="item">Russian</div>
            <div class="item">Spanish</div>
            <div class="item">Swedish</div>
            <div class="item">Turkish</div>
            <div class="item">Vietnamese</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>
        Voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
        incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
        voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur</p>

    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui approve button">Approve</div>
      <div class="ui button">Neutral</div>
      <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```